# Laravel S3 Upload Not Working. Path Returns False

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-8

The $path always returns false.

My code

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($request->file));
```

Please let me know what could have gone wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realized that first I've to upload the files to the server and then to the s3.

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($request->file));
```